# How to remove number inside the brackets with R?

Tags: r, regex

I have :

```
String=“text(2019),text1(2015),text2(Napoli 2018) . Text5(Milan 2019)
```

Desidered output:

```
text,text1,text2(Napoli 2018). Text5(Milan 2019)
```

Then, I want delete only (2019) , (2015) and not (Napoli 2018 ) and (Milan 2019)

Thanks !

Comment: gsub("\\(|)","",string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\(\d+\)` with empty string.

```
data <- c("text(2019),text1(2015),text2(Napoli 2018) . Text5(Milan 2019)")
gsub("\\(\\d+\\)", "", data)
```

Prints,

```
[1] "text,text1,text2(Napoli 2018) . Text5(Milan 2019)"
```

**[Online R demo](https://rextester.com/GVO9584)**